# Send mail (Java vs Php)

Tags: java, php, email

I have developed an app with a login. To help users I would like to send a mail reminding their credentials.. 2 solutions but 2 problems:

1) If I send the mail from the mobile phone (using my gmail account and mail.jar library) Google always reports a possible violation of my account or a suspect access, blocking it. I read several forum page about remove this feature but some people say that Gmail is built to be used by a single person

2) If I send a mail from a php page (using the function mail($mailto,$subject,$message,$header) several mail server put automatically this email into the trash folder.

Any suggestion? How to solve this issue?
Thank you in advance

Comment: It is my "second" account of gmail..
If I have an alternative, of course I'll remove my account

Answer (score 0):

You could send mail in java (mail.jar or mailServices of Spring Framework). I suggest you to use a mail provider service to send mail. It's better because there many things to care with when you send email ( email does not exist, delay of receiving the email, the current status of email sent, received or read...)

Comment: what do you mean with a "mail provider service"? Do you have a provider in particular that you can suggest?

Comment: Entreprise which job is manage sms so you could use their apî to send mail.